# import csv as a hashtable with 2 keys

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have a table with equal rows and columns

| Groups | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

I would like to import it into some type of variable where there output from $h[C].C is equal to 3.

I tired with a simple import command but the formart is giving me trouble to input it into the hashtable. Also is hashtable the best format?

Comment: not sure why the table is showing as it is. It looks formatted in the preview.

Comment: There was an empty line missing, but yes, it did look ok in the preview. There is apparently numerous posts on meta about live preview and rendered question being different when involving tables, here's one - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404376/rendered-view-requires-blank-line-before-tables-but-preview-accepts-both - so I guess they know about it.

Comment: Yeah, a `hashtable` is fine for this, though, on PowerShell, you would normally reference `$h[C,C]` with this syntax `$h['C'].C`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks! Now how do I populate it from the CSV. Sometype of nested for loop?

Comment: You can look at [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2), specifically at it's `-AsHashtable` switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Import-Csv` to get an array of PsCustomObjects and convert that to a nested Hashtable like.

I'm  using a here-string example, but in real life you would do `Import-Csv -Path 'X:\WhereEver\theTable.csv'`

```
$data = @"
Groups,A,B,C,D
A,1,0,0,0
B,0,1,0,0
C,0,0,3,0
D,0,0,1,2
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$h = @{}
$data | ForEach-Object {
    $props = @{}
    $_.PsObject.Properties | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne 'Groups' } | ForEach-Object{ $props[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
    $h[$_.Groups] = $props
}

$h['C'].C  # --> 3
```